# How to set ImageView as borders in Android

Tags: java, android, imageview, border

[Content-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQYsp.jpg)

[border-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDUb0.jpg)

How can I set `ImageView` as borders, being repeated horizontally and vertically, as shown in the Content-image

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Use Constraintlayout and guideline

Comment: I'm relatively new to Android development. If you're familiar with CSS, it has a property called border-image. So I am asking, "How can I achieve this on this Android?" as you can see in the content-image. I searched a lot but didn't find any solution to this problem.

Comment: There is no such thing in android . you need to create a layout for such arrangement ..
use `Constraintlayout` align the images .. better create a separate layout file and use if everywhere.